# Logout other devices with multiguard

Tags: laravel, middleware, guard, remember-me

Regarding this feature, I have uncommented the `middleware` in web group, `\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\AuthenticateSession::class` and `logoutOthersDevices()`  works fine after enabling this.

However, since I am using multi guard, if I try to login with second guard, then first guard get log-out by this `middeware`.

Checking the `middleare` `handle()` method I see that I was logout here:

```
        if ($request->session()->get('password_hash') !== $request->user()->getAuthPassword()) {
            $this->logout($request);
        }
```

How to make this new `middleware` in multi guard scenario? I am not sure how to handle this.

Because all works fine if you are logged-in with both guards, also remember me. Each remember me cookie is save with guard name like remember_web_xxx and remember_admin_xxx.

This issue happen only with this `middleware`, since I want to add `logoutOthersDevices`, which require this `middleware`.

Thanks

Comment: create different login routes for the different types of users.

Comment: I have already two different login routes/controllers and views. I am able to login in "web" guard and then in "admin" guard. However, when enabling this middleware, then after login via web, when I enter in admin login, this middleware log me out because as session and password are different hash in this case. All works fine without this middleware.